# How to cast a subscript member to NSArray Swift 3

Tags: json, swift3

Returns an error message: Type ‘Any’ has no subscript members in last 2 lines of code.  I can^t solve this for NSArray in Swift 3: Any thoughts?

```
 let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataObject!, options: [])) as! NSDictionary
_ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataObject!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
```

then

```
  struct Weekly{
  var dayZeroTemperatureMax: Int
  var dayZeroTemperatureMin: Int

  init (weatherDictionary: NSDictionary) {

    let weeklyWeather = weatherDictionary["daily"] as! NSDictionary
    let weeklyForcast = weeklyWeather["data"] as! NSArray

    //DAY ZERO

    dayZeroTemperatureMax = weeklyForcast[0]["temperatureMax"] as! Int  
    dayZeroTemperatureMin = weeklyForcast[0]["temperatureMin"] as! Int
    } 
   }
```

Comment: let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataObject!, options: [])) as! NSDictionary

Comment: let weeklyWeather = Weekly(weatherDictionary: weatherDictionary)

Comment: !! http://json.org/example.html Please check here. Hope you understand what is JSON!

Comment: Instead of "let weeklyForcast = weeklyWeather["data"] as! NSArray", try the SWIFT array. I mean instead of type casting to NSArray, typecast to [Int]. I am assuming that your contains only Int values. Else, SWIFT will infer it to be of type [Any].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to this  :

```
let weeklyWeather = weatherDictionary["daily"] as! [String: AnyObject]
let weeklyForcast = weeklyWeather["data"] as! [[String: Any]]
```

in this same project you might need to change this too (in WeatherAlerts) :

```
 init (weatherDictionary: [String: Any]) {

    if let weatheralerts = (weatherDictionary["alerts"] as? [[String: Any]]) {

        userAlert = weatheralerts[0]["title"] as! String

    } else {
        userAlert = ""
    }
}
```

I don't really know the reason to change this , if anyone have an explanation please comment here.

but in the same [project](https://github.com/Mav3r1ck/Project-RainMan) I had a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error [here](https://github.com/Mav3r1ck/Project-RainMan/blob/master/Stormy/ViewController.swift#L209) , do you have any idea? what change about URLSessionDownloadTask ?

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked brilliantly.  I also have no explanation, but it works!